# Encrypt user id for link usage

Tags: ruby, encryption

I need to make autologin links, so what is best way of doing it?
How I encrypt user_id with salt, to make links as such `login.com/?login=<salted_id>` and how then get from this `salted_id` my id back??

I'm on my Ruby On Rails project

Comment: Don't use encryption. Generate a random token.

Comment: But I can't have one more field in database

Comment: But where would you store the salt? It can't be static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add an extra `login_token` table to the database and allow each `user` to have many `login_tokens`. Each token in that table can just be a random string. This allows you to store further information on that table. For example: when and why did you create that token, was the token ever used, how long is it valid?

Loading the user is than a simple `LoginToken.find_by_token(params[:token]).try(:user)`.